# Enable LEDs on Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, peripheral

I'm using an MBP running Big Sur. I've attached a [Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/microsoft-ergonomic-keyboard/93841ngdwr1h) over USB, and am finding that the LEDs on the keys (Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock) never turn on. I've confirmed that the keyboard LEDs *do* work when connected to non-Mac machines (including an Android phone).

Is there any way to enable them on the Mac as well?

Comment: Not unless Microsoft provide macOS drivers.

Comment: Presumably the keyboard firmware implements the [USB HID standards](https://wiki.osdev.org/USB_Human_Interface_Devices#LED_lamps) for a keyboard, so no additional drivers should be needed for the lights to work. They do work on an Android phone I tried, and I doubt Microsoft contributed drivers for this keyboard to Android or to the Linux kernel.